# Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined In Angular 7

Tags: angular

I want to implement data table in my angular app but it shows an error like `Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined` i google it several time but i could not find any proper solutions so how can i solve this issue.

install all npm

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install datatables.net --save
npm install datatables.net-dt --save
npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
npm install @types/datatables.net --save-dev
```

in angular.json file added these codes

```
"styles": [
"node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css"
],
"scripts": [
"node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
"node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"
]
```

this is my code

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('dataTable') table;
    dataTable: any;



    ngOnInit(): void 
    {
        this.dataTable = $(this.table.nativeElement);
        this.dataTable.DataTable();
    }
```

inside my table

```
<table #dataTable class="table table-bordered table-striped">
```

Comment: I would suggest you not to use Jquery with Angular instead go for mat table https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

Comment: i did it @ViewChild('dataTable') table: ElementRef; but not work

Comment: @MaihanNijat he is using jquery data table

Answer (score 0):

for this question

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';


  @ViewChild('dataTable', {static: false}) table: ElementRef;


    ngAfterViewInit(){
        this.dataTable = $(this.table.nativeElement);
        this.dataTable.DataTable();
    }
```

But  I would suggest you not to use Jquery with Angular instead go for [mat table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview)

Answer (score 0):

`@ViewChild` queries are set before `AfterViewInit` hook  [[docs]](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#description). Try this way;

```js
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild("dataTable", { static: true }) table: any;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.table.nativeElement);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is correct but we shouldnt use jquery with Angular

Answer (score 0):

```
@ViewChild('dataTable') table: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  if (!this.table) return;
    this.dataTable = $(this.table.nativeElement);
    this.dataTable.DataTable();
}
```

Use condition to avoid error if table is null.

Answer (score 0):

In general that error means that the object you are accessing the 'nativeElement' property on is undefined.

In this example, [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) doesn't set your `table` property at the point in the [component lifecycle](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) that `ngOnInit()` is called. You need to use `ngAfterViewInit()` or `ngAfterViewChecked()`:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void 
{
    this.dataTable = $(this.table.nativeElement);
    this.dataTable.DataTable();
}
```

For this particular situation a better way to handle it would be to create a directive outside your component that would do this.

Far better however would be to stop using jquery because angular wants to own the dom.  For instance if your table data changes jquery would get out of sync and it probably will cause issues.   Check out [angular material table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview)...